# netlify not picking up redirect attempts for nextjs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, hosting, web-hosting

I recently converted a react site to use next.js for seo, and it runs perfectly fine aside from the fact that it doesn't render index.js correctly. I then converted all the code on index to exist at url.com/home, and decided to just redirect from url.com to url.com/home. the only problem is that it doesn't seem to be working once deployed to netlify.

I have tried adding the redirect from url.com to url.com/home via index.js, next.config.json, a _redirects file, and a netlify.toml file. all in the correct syntax and all working when I run the code locally. but when I push the code to netlify and it deploys I still get the exact same issue every single time in which url.com just displays a blank page and doesnt redirect anywhere.

has anyone had this issue? whether it be the blank page issue or the issue of netlify not implementing redirects, fixing either of the two issues would help me greatly and I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// pages/index.js

import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const IndexPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Redirect to the homepage when accessing the base URL
    router.replace('/home');
  }, []);

  return null; 
};

export default IndexPage;
```

_redirects
`/ /home 301`

```
netlify.toml
[[redirects]]
  from = "/"
  to = "/home"
  status = 301
```

I have three redirects in place counting the index.js page. but the index page never renders, and the redirect never happens, and the other two files I'm trying to use for the redirect are seemingly not being picked up by netlify. there are no issues in the build log, but I've sent netlify an email to try and get further answers.

update: the issue was apparently with netlify because as soon as I switched providers the issue disappeared and everything worked as expected.